# howto catch a error when i do "read" on a list of integer?

Tags: haskell

i need help, i have to read a list like this `["1", "2", "3"]` and make a list of integer of it `[1,2,3]` so i use `read`.

the problem is, when the list looks like `["1", "2", "a"]` the programm quits because of the error that there is a char in it.

how to check or throw an error to prevent this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `reads`, not `read`.

```
Prelude> :m Data.Maybe
Prelude Data.Maybe> (map (fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads) ["1", "2", "3"]) :: [Maybe Integer]
[Just 1,Just 2,Just 3]
Prelude Data.Maybe> (map (fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads) ["1", "2", "a"]) :: [Maybe Integer]
[Just 1,Just 2,Nothing]
Prelude Data.Maybe>
```

Comment: Note that this will happily turn "123abc" into `123`. You need to also check that the second element of the tuple is empty to prevent this.